# How to get UV coordinate area of rendered material

Tags: three.js, webgl

Is it possible to know what area of the material is rendered on the display? I think Three.js already doing this right?

I trying to make Zoom level. When someone zooming it will become a good resolution.
I making CUBE using 6 planes and I’m trying to know the coordinate of the material and which areas are rendered on display.

The below example shows on the display only some areas of TOP, some areas of RIGHT and FRONT.
If I know which coordinate of material is rendered on the display, I’ll draw a good resolution of the image on the canvas.

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: You could use a raycaster. When it intersects an object, it'll give you the point in 3D space, uv coordinates, etc... https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObject

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried raycaster but it's require origin : Vector3, direction : Vector3.  Also is it possible to know if there is a 3 plane but only half of each plane rendered on the display, is it possible to know what area of plane rendered on the display ?

Comment: You don’t need origin or direction. You could use the x/y screen position from the camera. Look at the source code [in this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=rayc#webgl_raycast_texture). It uses `raycaster.setFromCamera()`

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried to use raycaster and see all the returned parameters  intersects[0].object, But I didn't find area of material position which is only rendered on the display. Using raycaster i know what object rendered on the display but I don't know what part of object material rendered on the display ?

Comment: Seems like you didn’t read the link I gave you. You’re looking at .object but the intersection gives you much more than that. It has `{ distance, point, face, faceIndex, object, UV, etc… }`. Here’s the documentation again: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObject